# C strcat() gives wrong appended string

Tags: c, strcpy, strcat

I am appending a string using single character, but I am not able to get it right. I am not sure where I am making mistake. Thank you for your help in advance. The original application of the method is in getting dynamic input from user.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void main(){
    int j;
    char ipch=' ';
    char intext[30]="What is the problem";
    char ipstr[30]="";
    printf("Input char: ");
    j=0;
    while(ipch!='\0'){
        //ipch = getchar();
        ipch = intext[j];
        printf("%c", ipch);
        strcat(ipstr,&ipch);
        j++;
    }
    puts("\n");
    puts(ipstr);
    return;
  }
```

Following is the output I am getting.

```
$ ./a.out 
Input char: What is the problem

What is h  e

 p
oblem
```

Comment: You are appending a single char instead of a nul-terminated string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

change

```
strcat(ipstr,&ipch);
```

to

```
strncat(ipstr, &ipch, 1);
```

this will force appending only one byte from `ipch`. `strcat()` will continue appending some bytes, since there's no null termination character after the char you are appending. as others said, strcat might find somewhere in memory `\0` and then terminate, but if not, it can result in segfault.

from manpage:

```
char *strncat(char *dest, const char *src, size_t n);
```

The strncat() function is similar to strcat(), except that

- it will use at most n characters from src; and
- src does not need to be null-terminated if it contains n or more characters.

Comment: That worked very well in this case, as well as with getchar(). Many thanks for even giving details. It improved my understanding of string handling.

Comment: +1 about "src does not need to be null-terminated if it contains n or more characters."

Comment: I like the clever use of `strncat` in this solution.

Answer (score 3):

`strcat` requires its second argument to be a pointer to a well-formed string. `&ipch` does not point to a well-formed string (the character sequence of one it points to lacks a terminal null character).

You could use `char ipch[2]=" ";` to declare `ipch`. In this case also use:

- `strcat(ipstr,ipch);` to append the character to `ipstr`.
- `ipch[0] = intext[j];` to change the character to append.

---

What happens when you pass `&ipch` to `strcat` in your original program is that the function `strcat` assumes that the string continues, and reads the next bytes in memory. A segmentation fault can result, but it can also happen that `strcat` reads a few garbage characters and then accidentally finds a null character.

Answer (score 0):

strcat() is to concatenate strings... so passing just a char pointer is not enough... you have to put that character followed by a '\0' char, and then pass the pointer of that thing.  As in

```
/* you must have enough space in string to concatenate things */
char string[100] = "What is the problem";
char *s = "?"; /* a proper '\0' terminated string */
strcat(string, s);
printf("%s\n", string);
```

Comment: The OP modifies `ipch` in their program. Your alternative will not allows modification (but `char s[2] = "?";` would).

Comment: Of course, but he didn't say he was going to append chars one by one.

Comment: You could say that the OP said they were to append the characters one by one by posting a program that almost does append the characters one by one, modulo the bug under discussion.

Answer (score 0):

`strcat` function is used to concatenate two strings. Not a string and a character. Syntax-

```
char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src);
```

so you need to pass two strings to `strcat` function.

In your program

```
strcat(ipstr,&ipch);
```

it is not a valid statement. The second argument `ipch` is a `char`. you should not do that. It results in `Segmentation Fault`.

Comment: It could result in a Segmentation Fault, but it does not have to, and it doesn't in this particular case because with an ordinary compiler, `ipch` is placed on the stack, which is a long stretch of memory the program is allowed to access (and that almost certainly contains a null character).